# Center cards inside infinite row with Bootstrap 4

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3, bootstrap-4

I'm setting up a fullscreen slider and I want to center the cards inside this infinite row. I am using **Bootstrap 4**. I don't know how to set the `margin-left: -*px` automatically based on how many cards.

In my screenshot I've used 3 cards but the cards should be centered always.

HTML:

```
<div class="reviews">
  <div class="card card-review bg-dark text-secondary intro text-center">
   <p class="font-italic">Lorem Ipsum</p>
   <p class="text-white mb-0">Name</p>
  </div>
  <div class="card card-review bg-dark text-secondary intro text-center">
    <p class="font-italic">Lorem Ipsum</p>
    <p class="text-white mb-0">Name</p>
  </div>
  <div class="card card-review bg-dark text-secondary intro text-center">
    <p class="font-italic">Lorem Ipsum</p>
    <p class="text-white mb-0">Name</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

[image: Preview]